# is there a python code to find length of the file which is in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, size, content-length

Below is the code snippet. appreciate inputs on this

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
object_file = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=bucket_name, key=object_key)
file_size=object_file.content_length
print("Size of the file being processed:".format(file_size))
```

This code code prints blank output every time I try to print the file size

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
print("Size of the file being processed:".format(file_size))
```

to

```
print("Size of the file being processed: {}".format(file_size))
```

Comment: @padaleswaranjayaperumal Please consider accepting my answer if it helped :)